# i have some problems in mex file

Tags: c, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I use the Lindo software in my c-code and i want to mex it by Matlab.

I have these problems in using mex file:

```
 mex ex_sdp1.c
   Creating library C:\Users\AZINRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_n9pt9A\templib.x and object C:\Users\AZINRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_n9pt9A\templib.exp 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LScreateEnv referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LScreateModel referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSdeleteEnv referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSdeleteModel referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSloadLicenseString referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetVersionInfo referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetErrorMessage referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSloadInstruct referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSoptimizeQP referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetInfo referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetPrimalSolution referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetDualSolution referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetVariableNamej referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSgetConstraintNamei referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LSsetModelLogfunc referenced in function mexFunction 
ex_sdp1.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'ex_sdp1.mexw64' failed.
```

how can i fix them?

my include file is in the path C:\Lindoapi\include and the library in   C:\Lindoapi\lib\win32\lindo9_0.lib
     So I add these sentences: 
'     mex ex_sdp1.c -L
    Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
    Error using mex
    Access is denied.
    mex ex_sdp1.c -L -l
    Error using mex
    MEX cannot find library '' specified with the -l option.
     MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
     .lib
     lib.lib
     Please specify the path to this library with the -L option.
    mex ex_sdp1.c -L -I
    Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
    Error using mex
    Access is denied.
    mex ex_sdp1.c -L -I -l
    Error using mex
    MEX cannot find library '' specified with the -l option.
     MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
     .lib
     lib.lib
     Please specify the path to this library with the -L option'

Comment: There seems linking problem.

Comment: You need to read up on C linking

Comment: @Mohadese Soleimanpoor I updated your question. The way you provided the error message, everything between < and > was not displayed, which made it very difficult to make any sense of the error message.

Comment: If you take a look at the error message: it's searching for `<lindo9_0.lib>.lib`. You have to path the library name without `<>` and without extensions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those function names are not standard C functions,  Perhaps from some windows related library.

In any case, the link statement in your makefile (or on your command line) needs to include the appropriate library.

For gcc, on linux, the library would be included by appending the following parameters to the statement that links the files together

-LpathToLibrary -lshortLibraryName

for example of the math library were being used then

In the source file:

```
#include <math.h>
```

and in the compile command, append the following

```
-I/usr/include
```

and in the link command, append the following

```
-L/usr/lib/   -lm
```

for a windows OS, and for a different compiler, the details would be different.

For instance, if using visual studio, the library path and the library name and the include files path would be part of the setup for the current project

Comment: thank you for your reply.I apply all of your advises. but I have some errors that I explain them in Question. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This particular sample, ex_sdp1.c, is part of LINDO API C/C++ samples, it is **not** an off-the-shelf Matlab-ready code that you can build with 'mex'.

First, try to build and run the sample as a standalone application, i.e. outside Matlab framework. Once successful, you can actually write a Matlab version of the same application in the form M-file. There are several Matlab examples (M-files) using LINDO API from within Matlab using the 'mxlindo' interface. Matlab samples illustrating how to use 'mxlindo' are under 'lindoapi/matlab'. Check out 'lindoapi/matlab/readme.txt' for a quick start.